# Line integral of second kind over a circle: $\int \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I've just get stuck with some task of line integral:

$$\int \frac{xdy - ydx}{x^2+y^2}\quad \text{ over} \ x^2+y^2=R^2$$

I understand that I need to use polar coordinates, and I have such thing:

$$x = r \cos\theta\quad dx = -r \sin\theta d\theta$$

$$y = r \sin\theta\quad dy = r  \cos\theta d\theta$$

Then I put it in a task example and get:
$$\int (r^2 \cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta)d\theta/r^2 = \int d\theta$$

But from what to what should I integrate and is the result is right?

Comment: Is the numerator of the first expression supposed to be $x \,dy - y \,dx$?

Comment: @Travis, yeah that my mistake, as you written

Comment: If you're integrating over a circle once, $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, and this matches to the $\int d\theta$?

Comment: Yes it does. $\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're integrating over the entire circle, so the bounds are $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. The integral is

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta = 2\pi$$